# Different DPI on MacBook Pro and external monitors - what options are there?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, display, dpi

I have an external monitor connected to my MacBook Pro, the two screens have different DPIs. Ideally I would like them to be the same, but as this is not the case, the best option I can see is reducing the resolution of the MBP screen to bring its DPI as close as possible to the external monitor. This introduces scaling artefacts on the screen, as LCDs don't look good at non-native resolutions.

Is there a standard or best way of handling this, and if not, what other options are available?

Answer (score 2):

I put the monitors at a different distance from my eyes so the DPI (as perceived) is reasonably close.

Comment: Since there is no better solution, just ignore the problem (it's easy to get used to the jumpy pointer when traversing the boundary) or do this.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help but I stumbled across a tool that will let you inspect your factory dpi settings.

Quartz Debug -> UI -> Resolution

It's part of the dev tools. It allowed me to set my gtk dpi correctly using:

```
defaults write org.x.X11 dpi -int 72
```